# Error when manipulating NAs with mutate() and case_when()

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a dataset with many missing values for the year of death. I want to replace those NAs by the year of birth + 79 which corresponds to the life expectancy in the US.

```
num_df = num_df %>%
  mutate(
    gdc_cases.demographic.year_of_death = 
      case_when( 
         is.na(gdc_cases.demographic.year_of_death) ~ round(gdc_cases.demographic.year_of_birth + 79), 
        TRUE ~ gdc_cases.demographic.year_of_death)
    )
```

However, I obtain a message error and I am not sure how to fix it:

```
Error in mutate(., gdc_cases.demographic.year_of_death = case_when(is.na(gdc_cases.demographic.year_of_death) ~ : 

Caused by error in `` names(message) <- `*vtmp*` ``:
! 'names' attribute [1] must be the same length as the vector [0]
```

Thank you in advance!

**DATA**

[RData file available here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1vhBXxgI-tF5VKy1agdM0uNTe49LRGHFa/view?usp=sharing)

```
rse_gene
counts = assay(rse_gene)
genes = rowData(rse_gene)
sample = as.data.frame(colData(rse_gene))
num_df= sample %>% 
  dplyr::select(where(~!all(is.na(.x)))) %>%
  dplyr::select(where(is.numeric))
```

Comment: Don't you just need to change `gdc_cases.demographic.year_of_death == "NA"` to `is.na(gdc_cases.demographic.year_of_death)` ?

Comment: With quotes, `"NA"` is a string with the letters N and A, not a missing value. Without quotes, `NA` is a missing value. You need to use `is.na()` to test if something is a missing value.

Comment: Thank you for your messages, I've updated the code. However, the error is still the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error message isn't very clear here but the RHS elements of your `case_when` all need to be the same type. At the moment you have a *numeric* (the first case) and an *integer* (the second case).

Choose which one you want and coerce the other to match - given you're working with years, integer seems to make more sense:

```
num_df = num_df %>%
  mutate(
    gdc_cases.demographic.year_of_death = 
      case_when( 
        is.na(gdc_cases.demographic.year_of_death) ~ as.integer(round(gdc_cases.demographic.year_of_birth + 79)), 
        TRUE ~ gdc_cases.demographic.year_of_death)
  )
```

Comment: Right, Thank you very much!